# Does the phenomenon of ‘bad money drives out good’ (Gresham's law) apply to Ether?

Tags: contract-design, scalability, economics

In the case of coinage, it’s the tendency toward the substitution of all high value coinage with less valuable coinage.

In our case as the quantitative value cannot be changed in this manner, can there be instead a qualitative change?

For example, there seems to be a possibility that Ether derived from criminal activities could grow in proportion to all Ether used in transactions until every Ether transacted, on some distant future date, will have been used in some prior criminal activity. Similar to the phenomenon of how the majority of physical money in the US seem to acquire some drug residue over time.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question, there is no such thing as a non-fungible eth "coin" (ie "this particular wei was here, then was transferred there"), only a registry of transactions with balances updated accordingly (add a few eth here, remove a few there)

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth Every transaction has an associated history and can be traced back, so it seems like its possible on a wallet level basis. Like how a single dollar bill with drug residue over time causes all the bills in a wallet, otherwise clean, to accumulate drug residue.  Or how every wei transacted through the wallet associated with a big theft can be assumed to be associated somehow with those activities. This may matter in the future since the principle has already been established that certain activities are repugnant enough to justify splitting the chain.

Comment: It looks like you're not really asking a question. Where do you draw the line? Binance and FTX hot wallets are criminal too then?
Some related readings in this coinbase post: https://blog.coinbase.com/fact-check-crypto-is-increasingly-being-used-for-criminal-activity-and-is-a-haven-for-illicit-856a71dfb399

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth I’m not sure what you mean. The question is in the title, is this phenomenon actually possible? Or is there some mechanism, mathematical, logical, legal, etc., that prevents it from occuring?